# How to change a nested property in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have an object like the following:

```
myObject{
   name: '...',
   label: '...',
   menuSettings: {
      rightAlignment: true,
      colours: [...],
   },
}
```

I would like to change the rightAlignment value to be false. I'm having quite a bit of trouble trying to access and modify just this value, without having to rewrite the rest of the object. I tried myObject.find(...) which didn't quite suit, and now was trying

```
Object.assign(this.myObject, {menuSettings: {rightAlignment: false}});
```

Which wasn't working because I'm guessing I didn't access the property correctly. Is there any way to cleanly do this?

*Edit:* I realised that the array I was trying to modify actually contained multiple array objects. So the solution that worked for me was to iterate over each myObject in the array, and for each one, checking whether menuSettings existed (since it was an optional property that sometimes wasn’t included).

Then if it did exist I would:

```
this.myObject.menuSettings.rightAlignment = true;
```

Comment: Are you trying to treat the original object as immutable or do you just want to modify it in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the property accessor dot notation `.`:

```
this.myObject.menuSettings.rightAlignment = false;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation

Comment: I get an error stating "Property 'menuSettings' does not exist on type '...' ". Not 100% if this is the reason for the error, but myObject is initiated in ngOnInit() while the actions I'm trying to do are done in a class method which is called when the window is resized.

Comment: Ahh silly me… I didn’t see that this array was one which could multiple myObjects. So of course it would throw this error!

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close there. If I understand correctly, you want to merge an existing object with the latest value from another object. Which you can achieve by doing as;

```
myObject.menuSettings = Object.assign({}, myObject.menuSettings, { rightAlignment: false });
```

The way you're doing currently, is not wrong though. but you're replacing the entire `menuSettings` which then will remove your `menuSettings.colours`.

Or just access the property directly as per answer by Alexander.

```js
var myObject = {
   name: '...',
   label: '...',
   menuSettings: {
      rightAlignment: true,
      colours: ['...'],
   },
}

myObject.menuSettings = Object.assign({}, myObject.menuSettings, { rightAlignment: false });

console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer choz! I am unable to access menuSettings through the dot accessor direction I believe since the myObject is created during ngOnInit, whereas the update to rightAlignment is being done in a class method which is called on window resize events. I get an error stating "Property 'menuSettings' does not exist on type '...' "

Comment: Forget my last comment! I realise that the array could hold multiple myObjects which caused it to throw this error.